# Is there a downside for using __init__(self) instead of setup(self) for a nose test class?

Tags: python, nose

Running `nosetests -s` for

```
class TestTemp():

    def __init__(self):
        print '__init__'
        self.even = 0

    def setup(self):
        print '__setup__'
        self.odd = 1

    def test_even(self):
        print 'test_even'
        even_number = 10
        assert even_number % 2 == self.even

    def test_odd(self):
        print 'test_odd'
        odd_number = 11
        assert odd_number % 2 == self.odd
```

prints out the following.

```
__init__
__init__
__setup__
test_even
.__setup__
test_odd
.
```

The test instances are created before tests are run, while setup runs right before the test.

For the general case, `__init__()` and setup() accomplish the same thing, but is there a downside for using `__init__()` instead of setup()?   Or using both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `__init__` may work as a replacement for `setUp`, you should stick to `setUp` because it is part of the stylized protocol for writing tests.  It also has a counterpart, `tearDown`, which `__init__` does not, as well as class- and module-level counterparts which `__init__` does not.

Writing test classes is different than writing normal classes, so you should stick to the style used to write test classes.

Comment: I agree that if there is no use case for a test class `__init__`, using the  stylized protocol, `setup`, is a better choice for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are supposed to create a clean slate for the tests, and keep your individual tests isolated.

It appears the test instances (one per test) are created in one batch, while `setup` is called right before each test. If your setup needs to reset external state, you'll need to do this in `setup`; if you were to do this in `__init__` individual tests can screw up that external state for the rest of the test run.

Comment: This isn't true: a new test case instance is created for each test, so `__init__` is called as often as `setUp` is.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: So it is; the same premise still applies, just for external state then.. Thanks for the heads-up!