# __init__ variable not found in test class?

Tags: python-2.7, class, testing, nose2

I recently changed from using nose to nose2, however a lot of my testing code seems to have broken in the process. One thing in particular is the **init** variable i put in my test class "self.mir_axis" is giving this error:

```
mirror_index = mirror_matrix.index(self.mir_axis)
AttributeError: 'TestConvert' object has no attribute 'mir_axis'
```

This used to work with nose, however with nose2 my **init** variable for some reason is no longer registering. Am I missing something here? Im using python 2.7.3, and eclipse as an IDE btw.

```
from nose2.compat import unittest
from nose2.tools import params
from nose2 import session
from nose2.events import ReportTestEvent
from nose2.plugins import testid
from nose2.tests._common import (FakeStartTestEvent, FakeLoadFromNameEvent,
                                 FakeLoadFromNamesEvent, TestCase)#
# Import maya modules
import maya.cmds as mc
# Absolute imports of other modules
from neo_autorig.scripts.basic import name
from neo_autorig.scripts.basic import utils

# Test class for converting strings
class TestConvert(TestCase):
    counter = 0 # counter to cycle through mir_axes

    def _init__(self):
        mir_axes = ['xy', '-xy', 'yz', '-yz'] # different axes to be applied
        self.mir_axis = mir_axes[self.__class__.counter]
        self.__class__.counter += 1 # increase counter when run
        if self.__class__.counter > 3:
            self.__class__.counter = 0 # if counter reaches max, reset
        self.utils = utils.Utils(self.mir_axis, False) # pass module variables

    def setUp(self): # set up maya scene
        side_indicator_l = mc.spaceLocator(n='side_indicator_left')[0]
        side_indicator_r = mc.spaceLocator(n='side_indicator_right')[0]
        mirror_matrix = ['xy', '-xy', 'yz', '-yz']
        trans_matrix = ['tz', 'tz', 'tx', 'tx']
        side_matrix = [1, -1, 1, -1]
        mirror_index = mirror_matrix.index(self.mir_axis)
        mc.setAttr(side_indicator_l+'.'+trans_matrix[mirror_index], side_matrix[mirror_index])
        mc.setAttr(side_indicator_r+'.'+trans_matrix[mirror_index], side_matrix[mirror_index]*-1)

    def tearDown(self): # delete everything after
        mc.delete('side_indicator_left', 'side_indicator_right')

     def test_prefix_name_side_type(self): # test string
            nc = name.Name('prefix_name_side_type')
            existing = nc.get_scenenames('transform')
            self.assertEqual(nc.convert('test', 'empty', self.utils.find_side('side_indicator_left'),
                'object', existing), 'test_empty_l_object')
            self.assertEqual(nc.convert('test', 'empty', self.utils.find_side('side_indicator_right'),
                'object', existing), 'test_empty_r_object')

# run if script is run from inside module
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import nose2
    nose2.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with the snippet you posted:

The first one is `def _init__(self):` is missing an underscore; it should be `def __init__(self):`

The second one (and seems to be the reason for the error) is the fact that the first line in `_init__`, `mir_axes = ['xy', '-xy', ...`, should be `self.mir_axes = ...`

## Edit

You should use `setUp` instead of `__init__` regardless, according to [Ned Batchelder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14293535/5495253) of [Coverage.py](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy) fame. :)

Comment: Oh, must of missed that re-editing code to fit nose2. Now i'm getting an error saying 
`TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`